# Sorting and ordering by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a query which returns a result set like this:

```
Proj  |  release  |  releaseDt
1     |   2       |  1/2/2013
1     |   1       |  4/5/2012
2     |   1       |  [null]
3     |   1       |  22/2/2013
1     |   3       |  [null]
3     |   2       |  [null]
```

I need to sort this by `releaseDt`, but I need to have all the records for that `Proj` together.

After sorting, the result should be something like this:

```
Proj | release |   releaseDt
1    |  2      |   1/2/2013
1    |  1      |   4/5/2012
1    |  3      |   [null]
3    |  1      |   22/2/2013
3    |  2      |   [null]
2    |  1      |   [null]
```

How can I do this with SQL Server?

Comment: You need to use `order by` on that column.

Comment: no .. adding order by on release dt will order the whole resultset depending on  dt .. i want the corresponding rows for that proj to come together.

Comment: Did you try my answer? It should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to sort by the earliest release date for a project and then by the release date within a project.

You can get the earliest date using a window function, and then use that for sorting:

```
select t.Proj, t.release, t.releaseDt
from (select t.*, min(releasedt) over (partition by proj) as minrdt
      from t
     ) t
order by t.minrdt, t.proj, t.releaseDt
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is sort your table twice: first by `Proj`, then by `releaseDt`:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY
  Proj ASC,
  releaseDt DESC
```

Comment: i dont want orderby for proj.... since its totally dependent on which release date is the latest ..

Comment: @user1916649 I'm sorry, I don't understand you - could you rephrase your question?

Comment: my need is to sort the resultset with the latest releaseDt ,while keeping all the rows for a proj together.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
ORDER BY proj ASC, releaseDt DESC
```

Should do the trick!