# SQL order by two columns

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to order the following two columns:

Column1(1) match Column2(1,2,3,4,5,6) and

Column1(2) match Column2(1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
Column1    Column2
=======    =======
1          1
1          2
1          12
2          1
1          4
1          5
2          2
2          3
2          6
2          5
1          6
2          4
```

What I expect is as follows:

```
Column1    Column2
=======    =======
1          1
1          2
1          4
1          5
1          6
1          12
2          1
2          2
2          3
2          4
2          5
2          6
```

Thanks you guys!

=====================================================

**EDIT: 
edit column 2's data**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering (close enough, please take time to search) , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2583848/2864740 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091157/sorting-and-ordering-by-two-columns?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT   colum1, column2
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC
```

Comment: please see the edited table, column 2 is not ascending, how about this? I use order by column1 ASC, column2 ASC, the result I got is column 1 is ordered asc but column 2 not.

Comment: I figure out it, the reason is it order by the first digit, so I got the wrong result.